# How to show / hide same option from other dropdown using jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have 4 dropdown list `<td> <select class="encoderSelect" id="encoder1"><option value="None">-- Select User Command --</option><option value="1920*1080">1920*1080</option> <option value="320*240 to 1280* 720">320*240 to 1280*720</option> <option value="720*480">720*480</option> <option value="320*240 to 1920*1080">320*240 to 1920*1080</option> </select></td>`
there is another 3 dropdown also there id is like encoder2,encoder3 and encoder4. I want to hide a the options if it is selected in any 4 of this list. I used this code by call class name but its not worked.

```
$('.encoderSelect').change(function(){
        var optionval = $('.encoderSelect').val();
        console.log(optionval);
        $(".encoderSelect option[value='"+optionval+"']").hide();
        
    }); 

$('.encoderSelect').on("change", function(){
        $('.encoderSelect:selected', this).hide().siblings().show(); 
    }).trigger('change'); // this code also tried but not worked
```

can I implement this using class.? or I must go by using id..?

Comment: Please edit the question, use the `<>` icon on the tool bar to create a runnable example. Add the javascript and html to the interface, and choose a jquery version from the left-hand side. Even if you may be using a higher version that what is presented, use whatever the lastest reference is offered.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#encoder1').on("change", function(){
  var selected = $('#encoder1').val();
  for (var i = 0; i<$('#encoder1').children().length; i++) {
    var element = $('#encoder1 option:eq('+i+')');
    if ($(element).text() === selected) {
      $(element).hide();
    } else {
      $(element).show();
    }
  }
});
```

[demo](https://jsitor.com/6cleu3UBf)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. I hope it works fine and helps your project.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select.encoderSelec').on('change', function(event) {
      var prevValue = $(this).data('previous');
      $('select.encoderSelec').not(this).find('option[value="'+prevValue+'"]').show();    
      var value = $(this).val();
      $(this).data('previous',value); $('select.encoderSelec').not(this).find('option[value="'+value+'"]').hide();
    });
  });
</script>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/MARSF/6r4vLxd0/4/)